# tmux set-option -g prefix ½

Tags: tmux

This works for me:

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-g
bind-key C-g send-prefix
```

but this does not:

```
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix ½
bind-key ½ send-prefix
```

How can I use the ½ key as prefix?

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.6
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=C
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Works for me in Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, both in `konsole` and tty2. Tmux 2.6. For the record: I type `½` with AltGr+6.

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 18.04, too, in `konsole`. What could be the difference between our systems?

Comment: Not sure. I use Polish keyboard layout. How do you type `½`?

Comment: Danish keyboard: I have a ½ key (that I *never* use).

Comment: I changed to Danish. The `½` key is now the one between Tab and Esc. Still works in tmux.

Comment: @mosvy It's beyond my expertise. I can tell I use `pl_PL.UTF-8` and the `½` character seems to be `0xc2bd`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It actually does support them, I was wrong, and ½ works for me, too (`*.UTF-8`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for Unicode keys was added in tmux 2.3. Are you sure your tmux is new enough?

Does `tmux show -g prefix` show the change? Did you remember to restart tmux entirely after changing .tmux.conf?

Comment: Restarting _all_ `tmux` was the problem: I had a `tmux` running in another terminal.